# Global variable not recognized after remove and append of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a global variable `var $test = $('#test');` where `#test` id of div that initially exist in DOM. If i remove the div with `remove()` and append it again then the global variable  $test no longer recognizes the the newly appended div with id `#test`. What am i doing wrong. Why does this happen?

**Check http://jsfiddle.net/mr3C4/**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of creating a new element from the string, just append the original element:

```
var $test = $('#test');
$test.live('click', function() {
    $test.toggleClass('blue');  // 2. continues to reference $test
});

$('button').click(function() {
    $test.remove();
    $test.appendTo('body');  // <-- 1. append the same element that you removed
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/mr3C4/5/

That way your handler is still referencing the same element you have referenced in the `$test` variable.

This is because `$test` is referencing a specific jQuery object that references a specific element, which is no longer part of the DOM. You were recreating an idential element from a string in your original code.

---

...or you can use the [`detach()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) method instead of the [`remove()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) method if you want to keep jQuery data associated with it.

```
var $test = $('#test');
$test.live('click', function() {
    $test.toggleClass('blue');
});

$('button').click(function() {
    $test.detach();
    $test.appendTo('body');
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/mr3C4/6/

---

**EDIT:**

If you want to update your element, it is better to use the method above, and make modifications to the original.

If you can't do that because you're making a change that can't be made to the original, like changing the `tagName`, then create your new element, and update your variable.

```
var $test = $('#test'),
    x = '<p id="test"></p>';
$test.live('click', function() {
    $test.toggleClass('blue');
});

$('button').click(function() {
    $test.detach();
    $test = $( x ).appendTo('body'); // update the variable
});
```

You could even keep the same jQuery object, and just update the element:

```
var $test = $('#test'),
    x = '<p id="test"></p>';
$test.live('click', function() {
    $test.toggleClass('blue');
});

$('button').click(function() {
    $test.detach();
    $test[0] = $( x ).appendTo('body')[0]; // update the element at index 0
});
```

Comment: @patrick I noticed detach() doesn't work if i do $x = `<p id="test"></p>`; then `$x.appendTo('body')`. Even though the new element have the id test. I misunderstood how detach works. In you're example you are using the same element that was detached. I want to use a new modified element with modified inner html that has same id test. If i do that $test is no longer recognized.

Comment: @Pinkie: Yes, that is because the `#test` selector runs only once. Even after you remove it from the DOM, `$test` will continue to reference that element. If you create a new element from a string and append it, it doesn't change the fact that `$test` is still referencing the old one. It is better to modify the old one instead of replacing it. If you can't do that because you need a different type of tag, then simply update your variable. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @patrick Thanks. This works great. One minor issue. If $test is initially `draggable()` and i we replace it with a new element as per your last example,  then we lose the draggable functionality. Do i need to issue draggable() again to the new element. Why doesn't $test keep it's draggable properties. Check http://jsfiddle.net/mr3C4/7/

Comment: @Pinkie: All jQuery data, like handlers, stuff you set using `.data()` and some plugin behavior, is all stored in `jQuery.cache`. That jQuery data is associated with the elements via a serial number. If you inspect such an element in the console, you'll see that it has a property that looks something like `jQuery1603979026903398335: 2`, where `2` (or whatever) is its entry in `jQuery.cache`. So when you discard the old element, and generate a new one from a string, the new one is completely clean, and you need to reapply whatever handlers/data/plugins you previously had. This is part of the...

Comment: ...reason why you'd do whatever you can to reuse the original. That's what `.detatch()` was for. It is the same as `.remove()` except that it keeps all that data intact. But if you're turning your `<div>` into a `<p>`, it would seem that you have no choice but to create a new element, which means you'd need to reassign everything the original had. But if you're making changes to the element that *can* be done directly (like changing its `className` property, or something), then it is really best and more efficient to keep using the original. http://jsfiddle.net/mr3C4/8/

Comment: I will be using the same element but the things changing are the class names and html content. I'm trying to do everything in one step where i can just replace the old #test with the new #test that contains new class names and html content. The only way i can see myself doing this if is i keep #test, then apply new classes then apply html content inside. That's 2 steps. If i try to detach and add the new #test `<div class="new">new html content</div>`, it doesn't work as per my last example.

Comment: @Pinkie: Your desire to do it in one step destroys whatever jQuery-specific efforts you previously placed into enhancing the elements you're replacing. Not to mention that it is less performant to construct new elements rather than modifying existing ones. I don't know your specific requirements, but if for example there are 2 standard states for your element, you could create them both up front, store them both in variables `$A` and `$B` (or whatever) and simply swap them. `$A.replaceWith($B);` and `$B.replaceWith($A);`. I don't know if this meets your needs, but you won't get away from...

Comment: ...the fact that removing an element, and recreating an identical element from a string does not automatically associate previous jQuery data with the new one.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
var $test = $('#test'),
    str = '<div id="test"></div>';

$test.live('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('blue'); // here is the change, use $(this)
});

$('button').click(function() {
    $test.remove();
    $(str).appendTo('body');
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/mr3C4/3/

Although your code has another issue: If you intend to replace the `#test` element with a new one, you should also update the `$test` object because otherwise it refers to an DIV element that doesn't exist anymore which isn't useful.

Comment: Thanks, I do know about `$(this)` but my question was, what is the reason why $test no longer works if i remove/append the div. It initially works. Why doesn't it work afterwards.

Comment: @Pinkie Because in your code you have this: `$test.toggleClass('blue')`. Once you remove the DIV for the first time, the `$test` object doesn't refer to a DIV on the page anymore, but to a DIV that has been removed from the page. The new DIV on the page is not referenced by `$test`.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does this happen?

Because your original variable, $test, only ever refers to the div with id=test that was in the DOM when you declared the variable. Creating another element, even one with the same ID, does make it the same element you selected.

[This slide](http://fixingthesejquery.com/#slide26) contains another example you might find helpful.